# jQuery-based version of WMD editor (the SO version ideally)

Tags: jquery, wmd-editor

Here are the facts as they stand:

- I have a Django admin page although this question has nothing to do with Django.
- This page has multiple `<textarea>` boxes.
- I want to be able to go `$('textarea.wmd').wmd()` and see WMD editor bars appear over the top of my `<textarea>`s.

I've had a hack around with the original WMD version and a poke with [Dana's SO version](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)... But they're both global (attach to one ID). I've also seen [mooWMD](http://moowmd.awardspace.info/) which is a MooTools port of Dana's SO version but I've ridden the MooTools train before and I've no wish to haul that into my admin pages.

So quite simply, is there a jQuery port of Dana's (or other) code that can attach itself to multiple targets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this WMD jquery plugin after a quick search: https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd

It's a fork of Dana's SO version, and one of the major changes in the [Readme](https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd#readme) states that it **can work with multiple textareas in the same page**, and is a **jQuery plugin**.

Include the script on your page, and then call it on your textareas like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('textarea.wmd').wmd();
});
```

As far as I am aware, this answers your question.

Comment: https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd has many improvements over https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd